# String Out of Bounds Exception when creating subStrings using Integer List Elements

Tags: java

I am writing a function where substrings of an input sequence need to be created using elements of an `Integer List` (e,g, for `string s1`, substring can be `s1.substring(iList.get(i), iList.get(i+1)+1))`. I have set up an if statement to check that string length is always greater than `(i+1)` element of the list (which will be the end point in the substring). Still I get String Out of Bounds exception intermittently. My input strings are usually 80-90K characters and the error seems to be happening 70-80%. Due to the intermittent nature of the error, I am finding it difficult to troubleshoot. Below is my code:

```
    public static List<Integer> finalCPGIslands(List<Integer> iList,
        String iSeq, int width) {
    // Declare output list that contains final list of start and end
    // intervals
    List<Integer> oList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    // Add the first two elements anyways
    //if (cpgCriteriaCheck(iSeq.substring(iList.get(0), iList.get(1)+1))) {
        oList.add(iList.get(0));
        oList.add(iList.get(1));
    //}

    if (iList.size() > 2) {
        for (int i = 0; i < iList.size()-1; i += 2) {
            // The below IF is attempted to ensure that substring is always
            // valid
            if (iSeq.length()-1 > iList.get(i + 1)) {
                // While creating the substring in next line, I get String
                // index out of range: -9
                String testSeq = iSeq.substring(iList.get(i),
                        iList.get(i + 1) + 1);
                boolean check = cpgCriteriaCheck(testSeq);
                if (check) {
                    // If condition is met, add the indexes to the final
                    // list
                    oList.add(iList.get(i));
                    oList.add(iList.get(i + 1));
                }
                // If condition is not met, start removing one character at
                // a time until condition is met
                else {

                    int counter = 0;
                    int currentSequenceLength = testSeq.length();
                    String newTestSeq = null;
                    while (counter <= currentSequenceLength) {
                        counter++;
                        if (testSeq.length() > 2) {
                            newTestSeq = testSeq.substring(1,
                                    testSeq.length() - 1);
                            testSeq = newTestSeq;
                            if (newTestSeq.length() < width) {
                                counter = currentSequenceLength + 1;
                            } else {
                                boolean checkAgain = cpgCriteriaCheck(newTestSeq);
                                // If condition met, add the item to list
                                // and exit
                                if (checkAgain) {
                                    oList.add(iList.get(i) + counter);
                                    oList.add(iList.get(i + 1) - counter);
                                    counter = currentSequenceLength + 1;
                                }

                            } // End of Else
                        } // End of IF

                    } // End of While
                } // End of Else
            }

        } // End of For
    } // End of Else
    return oList;
}
```

I have mentioned in comments where I am getting the out of bounds error. Am I missing some check that I need to perform before doing substrings? Shouldn't the IF statement where I am checking to ensure that string length is greater than value of list element, cover for any strings out of bounds exception?

Comment: `String testSeq = iSeq.substring(iList.get(i), iList.get(i + 1) + 1);` --> try to print/debug and see what values return from `iList.get(i)` and `iList.get(i+1)` - it's probably not what you expect...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

whenever you do `.substring(from, to)`, ideally your should do this:

```
if (str != null && from >= 0 && to >= from && to <= str.length()) {
  // then it's safe
  String sub = str.substring(from, to);
}
```

Comment: `to <= str.length()` because `endIndex` in `String#substring(int, int)` is exclusive.

Comment: Thanks iluxa for providing the answer. This covers all the error conditions.